# The method 'map' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am getting the following error, how to sort it out?

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SearchBar(dirty, state: _SearchBar#31f4e):
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => SearchSuggestion)
```

[image]

```
 import 'dart:convert';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

 import 'listview.dart';

 class SearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
   const SearchBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State createState() {
     return _SearchBar();
   }
 }

 class _SearchBar extends State {
   bool searching, error;

   var data;
   String query;
   String dataurl = "http://localhost/search.php";

   @override
   void initState() {
     searching = false;
     error = false;
     query = "";
     super.initState();
   }


   navigateToNextActivity(BuildContext context, String dataHolder) {
     Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => SecondScreenState(dataHolder.toString())));
   }

   void getSuggestion() async {

     var res = await http.post(dataurl + "?query=" + Uri.encodeComponent(query));

     if (res.statusCode == 200) {
       setState(() {
         data = json.decode(res.body);
    
       });
     } else {
  
       setState(() {
         error = true;
       });
     }
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           leading: searching
               ? IconButton(
                   icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                   onPressed: () {
                     setState(() {
                       searching = false;
                  
                     });
                   },
                 )
               : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      
           title: searching ? searchField() : const Text("Search"),
           actions: [
             IconButton(
                 icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                 onPressed: () {
                   setState(() {
                     searching = true;
                   });
                 }), 

        
           ],
           backgroundColor: searching
               ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 111, 70, 173)
               : const Color.fromARGB(255, 111, 70, 173),
      
         ),
         body: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Container(
                 alignment: Alignment.center,
                 child: data == null
                     ? Container(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                         child: searching
                             ? const Text("Please wait")
                             : const Text("Search Job")
                    
                         )
                     : Container(
                         child: searching
                             ? showSearchSuggestions()
                             : const Text("No Data Found"),
                       )
            
                 )));
   }

   Widget showSearchSuggestions() {
     List suggestionlist = List.from(data["data"].map((i) {
       return SearchSuggestion.fromJSON(i);
     }));

     return Column(
       children: suggestionlist.map((suggestion) {
         return InkResponse(
             onTap: () {
       

               navigateToNextActivity(context, suggestion.id);
             },
             child: SizedBox(
                 width: double.infinity, 
                 child: Card(
                   child: Container(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                     child: Text(
                       suggestion.name,
                       style: const TextStyle(
                         fontSize: 20,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 )));
       }).toList(),
     );
   }

   Widget searchField() {

     return TextField(
       autofocus: true,
       style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
       decoration: const InputDecoration(
         hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
         hintText: "Search Job",
         enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
           borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
         ), 
         focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
           borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
         ), 
       ), 
       onChanged: (value) {
         query = value; 
         getSuggestion(); 
       },
     );
   }
 }


 class SearchSuggestion {
   String id, name;
   SearchSuggestion({this.id, this.name});

   factory SearchSuggestion.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
     return SearchSuggestion(
       id: json["id"],
       name: json["name"],
     );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying that you are calling the map on a null object. From it you can find where the problem is.

```
 List suggestionlist = List.from(data["data"].map((i) {
   return SearchSuggestion.fromJSON(i);
 }));
```

Here, you are calling map function on the data variable and you are trying to point out the "data" key in it. First of all, look at the data you are fetching. Verify if there is a key named "data". If not, it causes null.